# Why gravitational constant $G$ is used to calculate gravity between objects?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I have recently read about newtons law and i dont seem to understand why G is used. what is the logic behind G?

Answer (score 6):

Human beings invented the meter, the kilogram, and the newton.   Mother nature did not take those into account when she invented gravity and the magnitude of its force.  So humans had to add $G$ in order to get the correct size of the force when using meters, kilograms, and newtons to measure things.